# can you link .a files in gcc and if yes can you do multiple at once

Tags: c++, gcc, makefile, linker, sfml

i am tryeng to link SFML in a makefile currently i have this code in the makefile:

```
all:
g++ -Iinclude -Llib scr\enterpoint.cpp -lsfml-graphics -lFLAC -lfreetype -logg -lopenal32 -lsfml-audio-d -lsfml-system-d -lsfml-audio-s   -o work.exe
```

as you can see i am currently typing each .a file in individualy but is there a way to do at automaticly

Comment: Which `make` dialect are you targeting?

Comment: ehhh id did not really know there were make dialects but does this not just run the g++ comand?

Comment: Normally you have to tell your linker which non-default libraries to link to. It's not going to guess even if you include the headers. You may use some utilities to aid in telling it and help with dependencies if you like.

Comment: The short answer to your question is "no".  A make recipe is a shell script.  Make doesn't "build" or change that shell script in any way, other than by replacing make variables.  It has no idea whether the script will link a program, or copy some files, or anything else.  Further, how could it figure out what libraries you might need to link with your code?